# get_terms orderby numeric

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, order, terms

I am trying to order my terms numeric. But the problem is that nog every term is numeric. So I have the following terms (check image below) which some of them are dimensions and some are others. As you can see, my `get_terms()` function, orders them by name, but if they are numeric it only looks at the first character. So 1400mm is less than 500mm.

I don't know where I need to begin. Should I try to modify the result of `get_terms()` or hook into the [get_terms_orderby()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_terms_orderby/) function. But I have no idea how to do this.

My code to show the terms:

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'product-filter';
$parents = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'id' ) );
if( ! empty( $parents ) ) {
    foreach( $parents as $parent ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        echo '<h2>' . $parent->name . '</h2>';
        $children = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'child_of' => $parent->term_id ) );
        foreach( $children as $child ) {
            echo '<li><label><input type="checkbox">' . $child->name . ' (' . $child->count . ')</label></li>'; 
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the object `$children`.

The function to sort after you got the `$children` object can be like this:

```
usort( $children, function($a, $b) {
    $ai = filter_var($a->name, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $bi = filter_var($b->name, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if ($ai == $bi) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($ai < $bi) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Can you explain your code?

Comment: You can check http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php for more detail on `usort`. 
`filter_var($b->name, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)` to get number from your term name.

Comment: The aim of using usort is sorting your `$children` object by the object field. In here, we sorting by the name of term, but we want to sort by that value (numeric value), so we must extract the number from the name by using function I comment above.